# Update table column based on data in another column

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have a table being populated from a database as the page loads. Now, I have to create an extra column (Request Status)in there which gets populated from the database too, but its value depends on the data in corresponding row of another column(Request Id) (`<td id="requestId">`). Can I set an id for the table data like this? If there was just one row, could I have done the following?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function populateStatusDesc(){
    var reqId=document.getElementById('requestId').innerHTML;
    //Call AJAX function to pass requestId, receive response, set Request Status Data
}
```

How do I proceed here especially when there are multiple rows in the table?

Comment: try making it `getElementById("requestId")` (with quotes). If there are multiple rows, you'll need to use something like `var rows = document.querySelectorAll("tr"); for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) { var row = rows[i]; }`

Comment: Thankyou. your answer helped me in the right direction

Comment: If you've fixed the issue, feel free to close or delete your question, or answer it with the specific code you used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Mike McCaughan, the following code helped me to solve the problem stated above.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 window.onload=function populateStatusDesc(){
    var rows=document.querySelectorAll('tr');
    for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
        (function() {
        var row = rows[i];
        var reqid = row.cells[6].innerText;
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open("GET", "/servletname&reqid=" + reqid, true);
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
         ....
         ....
        };
        xhttp.send();
     })();
    }}
```